# How to create a "smart" checklist in excel or google sheets?

Tags: planning, tasks

We have a need to create a template checklist for our workflow and at a past job we had a template checklist that had various tabs for each process of the workshare that needed to be complete. For instance, that job was GIS related and each tab of the checklist contained what "theme" (ie, layer of the map) of the production mapping process needed to be complete before starting on the next theme. Each theme of the checklist was a tab that contained rows of things that needed to be complete for that theme and contributed to an overall percent complete that was tracked throughout each tab in the checklist. When a task was completed for that tab, we initialed a box, the percentage was updated, and we moved on to the next task. The first tab was always the same and would shape how the rest of the checklist was formatted based off of answers given to yes and no questions or from a series of dropdown menus.

What I'm really asking here is can all of this be completed through what is available in regular excel without needing to download other extensions? Can I make a look up table or a flow chart of some sort to model out the rest of the checklist? If so, where and how can this be completed within excel?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for formula which counts percentage of checked items on all tabs? If yes, then [here is an exemplar google spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZAn4vJ3psMN7p-QTu78DvKiEZ8H0ew9hzMsmACnyzWc/edit?usp=drivesdk) for you. You can add new tabs and just modify formula correspondingly.